# How to handle "it didn't work for me" type questions?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

For a while now, we've had [How can I take long exposures using a Nikon D7000 with wireless remote?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15338/how-can-i-take-long-exposures-using-a-nikon-d7000-with-wireless-remote), which has an accepted answer so I'm assuming working for the original poster. Today, a new user posted [How can I take long exposures on Nikon D7000 with a wireless remote?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/56072/how-can-i-take-long-exposures-on-nikon-d7000-with-a-wireless-remote) (I edited the question a bit; you may want to read the history to see the original version) noting that he'd tried the stuff in the original question but it didn't work for him.

The new question now has some close votes marking it as a duplicate of the older question, which doesn't seem to me like it's going to help the new poster much - he's already done the right thing and read the original question, and I don't think he can necessarily edit the original question or the answers in any way which doesn't significantly change the meaning, so what should he be doing?

Answer (score 4):

If the question is indeed different, then I would call that out in a comment, and I would, if you have the capacity, offer an answer. I think the best defense against a question being prematurely or improperly closed is to start offering answers, and get a discussion going about clarifying the issue so proper answers can be provided.

It is entirely possible and valid for people to have the same problem but require different solutions. In the end, we may end up merging the two questions, or we may retitle it to better reflect the actual issue of the second asker, which should help improve google search results and offset any future "repeat" questions.

Comment: The "new" question now has an accepted answer of "this isn't possible", which is in direct conflict to the original question which says "this is how to do it". I suspect we're missing something here, but I don't have a clue what it is :-(

Answer (score 0):

If the situation is different, *please* edit the title to be different. If the title is exactly the same, it *should* be closed as a duplicate, basically by definition.

If, on the other hand, it is the same question but the older one needs updating, this reduces to
[How Do I "Refresh" a Question?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1712/how-do-i-refresh-a-question)

On the third hand (so many hands!), if the earlier accepted answer is demonstrably, provably wrong, and the original question-asker isn't around to change the check mark, a mod *could* delete it.

Comment: In this _particular_ case, the author of the accepted answer to the original question amended it to cover the problem (30 second limit with wireless with this model).