# how the community deal with same outdated questions?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

This community is very professional and from a long time ago. the way that pros cant stand "new users" this is getting boring because they are forcing new users to follow some solution are outdated from the first place and didn't give the change to the new users to representing their new solution and experience.

Referring to my question: [What did pros do when their photos storage getting huge?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/58051/what-did-pros-do-when-their-photos-storage-getting-huge)

I am in a case that my question is voted for duplication twice, while some of the voters answer my question when it re reopened again !! they voted to close it again and now it is closed ... they are referring to an outdated question and a best answer from 2010, from 3 years and more while new technologies didn't appears yet.

so I suggest instead to mark duplicate an new question, I suggest to mark duplicate the old one to close a discussion happened from 3 years and continue or referring to the new one that consider new technologies, services hardware and cloud systems and services ... etc.

my suggestion is for duplicates that are outdated only.

Comment: I've updated your question to include a link to the question that you are referring to(I believe). If this is not the correct question please revise and link to the proper one.

Comment: this is the one .. thank you so much. of course your contribution will enrich any discussion. -- Thanks again.

Comment: I'm _very_ tempted to mark _this_ as a duplicate of [How Do I “Refresh” a Question?](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1712/how-do-i-refresh-a-question) :)

Answer (score 2):

If we were to mark the older version of this question a duplicate, wouldn't the next time we get this question the appropriate measure just be to mark your question as a duplicate? See where I am going with this? It would be an endless cycle of just marking older questions as duplicate as new ones are asked. Instead, here we historically have marked the newer ones as duplicates and left the older one active. The *preferred* method would actually be to ask a question that withstands the test of time and is not just valid for a few months.

Also, frankly this question is not that well suited for this particular Stack Exchange site. Obviously photographers store images, but technical(non-photographers) get very passionate about this topic and would likely provide even more indepth answers at other Stack Exchange sites. I haven't looked for the other questions, but I would gather hundreds if not more exist on sister Stack Exchange sites with this same question.

Comment: yes I got your point. and why going to sister Stack Exchange sites?! .. just click on Backup tag and you will see a bunch of question related to the same topic of my question is. but none of them marked as duplicate by the way.

Comment: @hsawires - Are you implying that the established users of this site somehow against newer users? That they(we) would mark a new users question as a duplicate simply because they are new? What exactly are you saying?

Comment: telling you the truth, it is hard to me to see all that "Responsiveness" from the answers and stop it just for the sake of duplication!! i cant see any other new contribution in the old questions and by closing the topic .. you close some potential experience that may appears. I know this topic is very passionate with Technical more that photographers but those day knowledge branches is  interfere with each other .. information security may concern as well as legal issues, financial and technicalities .. etc. why not including any topic "for graphics".

Comment: :) no I am not saying that ... sorry I don't mean it. I mean new users carry new technologies, maybe yes maybe not !!  and older answers maybe are outdated .. my suggestion is for outdated answers only. the way I like this site is for old experience. I Like to learn from your experience.

Comment: @hsawires This site is _not_ a discussion forum, and a question attracting discussion-style replies ultimately waters down the overall value. You might be better served by [chat].

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the time-based limitations of the question — and all that, I really think *is* covered at [How Do I "Refresh" a Question?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1712/how-do-i-refresh-a-question) and in [QA is Hard, Let's Go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) (pay no attention to the flippant title; it's good, helpful stuff) — the fundamental problem with this question is that you're asking what "professionals" do, but that's not what you *seem to actually want*. That is going to make the answers really ... random, at best.

I notice that you use "professional" again in *this* question, so maybe part of the misunderstanding is based around that. I would say that we are largely a *non-professional* and *semi-professional* community of photography enthusiasts. Many people here make *some* money with photography, and for a select, proud few, it's the primary source of income, but for most contributors here, it's a supplementary income or a pure hobby. There's nothing wrong with that, but it seems like you are using "pro" as a stand-in for "serious" — and that's not a helpful conflation.

I also don't think we're harsh to new users — overall, we're very welcoming: much more so than some other Stack Exchange sites, and *definitely* more so than many photography forums. In part, that's exactly because we stick to the topic, and keep the focus on answerable questions rather than discussions or opinion surveys. Ask some on-topic, focused questions about *photography* and you'll get great answers ***even if the question is very basic***.

And finally, you complain that the top answer of the question yours was marked a duplicate of is no longer applicable. I've re-read it half a dozen times now, and I strongly disagree — it's still the right answer today! And, it's the best possible type of answer for this question, because it doesn't tell you some personal idiosyncratic solution or recommend some current product: instead, it tells you the *key things any solution needs to cover*, which are going to be true just the same now and in a decade.

Comment: Agree 100%.  Way better out than my attempt!